# Crash on MTLDebugCommandBuffer lockPurgeableObjects in macOS 12 beta

Tags: xcode, macos, avfoundation, avplayer, macos-monterey

We see strange crashes when running our app on `macOS 12 beta` 21A5522h. We have not been able to fully identify the issue but it seems to happen on continue video playback in an `AVPlayer` after the app has been in the background. Xcode points to some random code (seems different every time and never in our own code)

[image]

And in the log we will see:

> -[MTLDebugCommandBuffer lockPurgeableObjects]:2103: failed assertion 'MTLResource 0x600002293790 (label: (null)), referenced in cmd buffer
> 0x7f7b2200a000 (label: (null)) is in volatile or empty purgeable state
> at commit'
>
> -[MTLDebugCommandBuffer lockPurgeableObjects]:2103: failed assertion 'MTLResource 0x600002293790 (label: (null)), referenced in cmd buffer
> 0x7f7b2200a000 (label: (null)) is in volatile or empty purgeable state
> at commit'

We tried finding the object 0x600002293790 and 0x7f7b2200a000 but this gave no additional information as to why the app crashes.

We are using a custom VideoCompositor: `AVVideoCompositing` and initialise the `CIContext` for the work done here with these options:

```
if let mtlDevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() 
    let options: [CIContextOption : Any] = [
        CIContextOption.useSoftwareRenderer: false,
        CIContextOption.outputPremultiplied: false,
    ]
    let context = CIContext(mtlDevice: mtlDevice, options: options)
}
```

Not sure this is an Xcode debug issue? or an actual issue as we have not seen it crash when not using Xcode to build our app.

Any information as to locating the source of the issue or a solution would be awesome.

Update:

We seem to see messages before the crash that relate to the screen on most crashes.

> ****[48028:857651] [] [15:53:06.503] FPSupport_GetDisplayRefreshInformation signalled err=-12780
> (kCMBaseObjectError_ParamErr) (CGDisplayModeGetRefreshRate returned 0)
> at FigPlayerSupport.m:3198
>
> ****[48028:857658] [] [15:53:06.548] customVideoCompositor_CopyProperty signalled err=-12784
> (kFigBaseObjectError_PropertyNotFound) (unrecognised property) at
> FigVideoCompositor_Custom.c:581

Or this one:

[image]

Comment: Crash still occurs on Xcode 13 (13A233) on macOS 12.0.1. Still can't pinpoint where the crash originates.

Comment: Also still happens to me with PDFView on MacoS 12.6.3. I can't even access the PDFView from the `NSViewRepresentable` without crashing the app. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Fabian, we did not... We never found why this happened. But never had a client with the crash in release ever. We marked it as Xcode issue.... and went on with our live ;)

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! I think it doesn't crash in release because Metal sanity checks are not compiled in there: Edit Scheme -> Diagnostics -> Metal API validation. That's at least what I'm trying out atm :)

Comment: You might be right about that indeed.